Field extension corresponding to multiplication by n isogeny of an elliptic curve
Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve over a field (take it as a number field or a local field if necessary). If $E[2]$ is defined over $K$, then we can associate the multiplication by $2$ isogeny to a biquadratic extension of $K(E)$. This is well-known from the 2-descent calculation. We can write down the extension very explicitly.
Can we do this for any $n$? And what happens if $E[n]$ is not defined over $K$?

Q1: Yes. Q2: Then it's not a Galois extension.

Thanks for the reply. Do you know some reference for Q1?
